# Data import wizard not importing data to mapped field

Tags: data-import-wizard

I am trying to import data to a custom picklist field for accounts (all permissions for field are correct). When importing, the data matches the field and the available values, and is mapped correctly to the field. I am able to import with no errors, but the data does not actually show up in the field. I've tried a ton of troubleshooting options but cannot figure out why the field is not populating through import. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using an object id to match in the import?

Comment: No, I'm matching by Field name.

Comment: Make sure no other fields are mapped to the `Contact` object, since the Data Import Wizard only has the `Accounts and Contacts` option.  Also, check to make sure there are not two fields with the exact label (i.e. standard field "Type" vs. a custom field you created called `Type__c` which has the same label "Type")